# Start Activity only if e-mail was sent

Tags: java, android

I'm having a little bug in my code, but the app goes like this:
User clicks on a button and that button launches an Intent for sending an e-mail. Now, if user sucessfully sends that e-mail, he should be taken to `PaymentCompleteActivity` and if not, `MainActivity` should be launched.

My idea was to check if the email was sent in `onActivityResult()` but it's not working, even on successfull email sent, it redirects to `MainActivity`

Here's my code:

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com", null));    
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myTextFiles); 
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."), 1);


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ProceedActivity.this, PaymentCompleteActivity.class));
            finish();
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ProceedActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: can you please share whole code..

Answer (score 0):

Email is not part of the API. `startActivityForResult` will return the  once you pressed the send button even if it is not sent. SO it will always call `resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Do something like write a simple function that connects to the SMTP and send email